# How do I get the value of checked radio button in PyScript?

Tags: python, pyscript

I would like to make 3 radio buttons and I would like to get the value of checked one when I press a button.

```
<py-script>
<input id="rad1" name="choice" type="radio">
<label for="rad1">1</label>
<input id="rad2" name="choice" type="radio">
<label for="rad2">2</label>
<input id="rad3" name="choice" type="radio">
<label for="rad3">3</label>

<button id="btn">Go</button>

<py-script>
from js import document 
from pyodide import create_proxy

def on_btn_click(event):
    global choice
    checked_value = ___???___              ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← 
    choice = checked_value

button = document.querySelector("#btn")
button.addEventListener("click", create_proxy(on_btn_click))
</py-script>
```

What is missing in the `??? ← ← ← ← ← ← ←`  in order to grab the checked value in the function handler?

Comment: In JavaScript, it would be `if(event.target.checked) checked_value = event.target.value;`.

Comment: how about something like `document.querySelector("#rad1").checked`,  `document.querySelector("#rad2").checked` and `document.querySelector("#rad3").checked` ? And if you want to use checkboxes to seleect one value then they may need the same `name=` and you shoould select by name. Shortly: it needs to learn `HTML` and `CSS` (and `JavaScript`)

Comment: @furas if I had a `name="choice"` how I would check the checked one. I know CSS, HTML and JS but I don't know how PyScript does inside handler function. Does it accepts regular JS inside? like 
`var ele = document.getElementsByName('choice');`

Answer (score 1):

You may check every radio button separatelly and use `if/else` to set correct value

```
document.querySelector("#rad1").checked

document.querySelector("#rad2").checked

document.querySelector("#rad3").checked
```

But if you have the same name in all radio buttons then you can use `name` and pseudo-selector `:checked` to get only checked radio button

```
document.querySelector("[name='choice']:checked").id
```

And if you add `value="1"` directly in radio button then you can get value

```
document.querySelector("[name='choice']:checked").value
```

---

BTW:

If you don't have other radio buttons with different name then you could reduce it to

```
document.querySelector(":checked").value
```

---

Minimal working code which displays selection in JavaScript console (in DevTools)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<input id="rad1" type="radio" name="choice" value="1"><label for="rad1">1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="radio" name="choice" value="2"><label for="rad2">2</label>
<input id="rad3" type="radio" name="choice" value="3"><label for="rad3">3</label>
<button id="btn">Go</button>
    
<py-script>
from js import document 
from js import console
from pyodide import create_proxy

def on_btn_click(event):
    global choice
    
    console.log(event)
    #console.log('#rad1: ' + document.querySelector("#rad1").checked)
    #console.log('#rad2: ' + document.querySelector("#rad2").checked)
    #console.log('#rad3: ' + document.querySelector("#rad3").checked)
    console.log('id: ' + document.querySelector("[name='choice']:checked").id)
    console.log('value: ' + document.querySelector("[name='choice']:checked").value)

button = document.querySelector("#btn")
button.addEventListener("click", create_proxy(on_btn_click))
</py-script>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Console in Firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments said,

```
document.querySelector("#rad1").checked
```

should do the trick. You can do it this way in javascript and this is pretty much the same (ofc not identical but still).